# C++ partition based on internal condition

Tags: c++, stl, partition

Using std::partition can be used to partition a range into two partitions 
using a boolean condition that tells whether an element is in the first or second partition.

Can you make std::partition work when the condition itself depends on the which is in the first or second range?

For example, partition a vector of ints into two  partitions if possible such that for every element x in the second partition there is an element in the first partition y such that abs(x - y) > n (where n is an input given to you).

Comment: No - `std::partition` considers each element independently.

Comment: Your example is trivially solved by always leaving the second partition empty without moving any elements at all. There must be more to the problem you are trying to solve.